# Why are there two users with same name?

Tags: users

When I execute `users` command, it output two users with same name. Why are there two users? I'm pretty sure that I created just one user.

i.e

```
username@Computer:~$ users
```

gives following output

```
username username
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste those results?

Comment: @JohnRambo he just cut out the **actual** username and computer name...

Answer (score 14):

The `users` command prints the user names of users currently logged in to the current host, not the list of users you created on your computer.

In your case, it returns the same user name twice because you are probably logged in twice.

You can check by using the `who` command (show who is logged on):

```
felix@computer:~$ who
felix    pts/0        2013-02-04 06:40 (:0.0)
felix    pts/5        2013-02-04 06:42 (:0.0)
felix@computer:~$ users
felix felix
```

See the manual pages for more information (`man 1 users`).

Comment: I didn't logged in twice, it is by default. Why there are two users logged in anyway?

Comment: Maybe because you have two open terminals?

Comment: Run `users` in aterminal. Now open another terminal run it again (`users`). You can see incerase in number.

Answer (score 0):

The users command prints the user names of users currently logged in to the current host, not the list of users you created on your computer.

This not limited to users signed in form graphical sign in screen, but also those logins via `sudo`.

You can check that by running `users`, then logging in to another shell session with sudo running `sudo -su <user_name>` or even just `sudo` if you want root user. Run `users` from here or any other session, you could see another user entry.

One thing to note, is that the list contains users that have run `sudo`, not the users sudo switched to. For example,

1. if you run `users` as non-root and got *"someuser someuser"*
2. Then run `sudo sh` to get shell as root.
3. If you test here by running `users`, you will get *"<user_you_ran_sudo from> someuser someuser"*
4. Then run either another `sudo sh` or `sudo -s -u <user_name>`
5. You will get additional entry for *"root"*.

This is the case in my Linux version 6.0.0-kali6-amd64.

Comment: This is a repeat of the existing answer.